# Exactly what does it mean that CAD file is georeferenced?

Tags: georeferencing, dxf, dwg

According to a post like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316223/importing-a-georeferenced-dwg-dxf-into-qgis/319421#319421), a DWG/DXF can be "georeferenced", but not all are. I guess the same is true for other CAD formats too. But *exactly* what does that mean that a CAD file is georeferenced?

Comment: @GBG: It sort of answers. I actually asked the other question. And when I wrote the question it was twofold, 1) exactly what does it mean 2) how to check. But PolyGeo edited my question to only ask the latter part. I assume he thought the question was being too broad; being two questions in one. So after his edit, I created this question, and I believe the question is substantial and essential enough to have its own question on stackexchange, even if I already mostly have it figured out.

Comment: Please don't ask two-fold questions. As you can see, they don't always get multi-answers.

Comment: @Vince: I think that sounds like good general advice :) Now I just need this question reopened then, so there is opportunity for someone to provide (possibly better) answers to this part of the question.

Comment: That general advice is the main purpose of the [Tour]. The other question's answer addressed this topic adequately, so I won't vote to reopen.

Comment: Hi there! Can you clarify what part of the idea of georeferenced/non-georeferenced CAD files is confusing to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In surveying, we called "[the world file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file)" the georeferenced portion of a file. It tells the GIS or mapping software where the file is located and at what scale to display it at.

If a CAD drawing/file is georeferenced, it means this location and scale data is embedded in it and can be used to place its contents on the map appropriately.

DXF file: older/simpler/smaller files, created by Autodesk, open source, cannot contain this georeferenced data (so manual placement is needed)

DWG file: bigger files, also created by Autodesk, proprietary, primarily made for AutoCAD, *can* contain georeferenced information

Answer (score 0):

I would also point that out here, since no one brought that up. When someone gives you a DXF or DWG file, you cannot modify it. You will also have to export it to another file to work on it.